# How do update an activity properties from an intent?

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently have a situation where I am trying to use a button that loads a dialog. When the dialog opens it allows you to choose a colour and then that colour selected is used to define the button you originally clicked. However am really stuck.

Main class

```
package dom.MasterMind.Com;


public class NewGameActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newgame);

    Button choiceOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choiceOne);
    Button choiceTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choiceTwo);
    Button choiceThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choiceThree);
    Button choiceFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choiceFour);



    final ColorPicker dialog = new ColorPicker(this);

    choiceOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog.show();

        }
    });

    choiceTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog.show();

        }
    });

    choiceThree.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    choiceFour.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog.show();

        }
    });
}
}
```

Dialog class

```
package dom.MasterMind.Com;

public class ColorPicker extends Dialog{
public ColorPicker(Context context) {
    super(context);

    setContentView(R.layout.colorpicker);

    Button btnBlack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBlack);
    Button btnBlue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBlue);
    Button btnGreen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGreen);
    Button btnPurple = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPurple);
    Button btnRed = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRed);
    Button btnYellow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnYellow);

    final Button test = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choiceOne);

    btnBlack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dismiss();
            test.setBackgroundColor(R.id.btnBlack);

        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [android binding](http://code.google.com/p/android-binding/) library, it allows you build more flexible [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)-oriented solution which solve your problem as well, you just need setup bindings and commands once and such synchronization/updates would work automatically.

Answer (score 0):

if choiceOne button is on newgame layout
you cannot use in colorpicker layout

try send color from dialog class to main class
then change button's color  in main class

and

I think `R.id.btnBlack` is not color 
try `Color.parseColor("color code")` eg. `#ffffff`